# show/hide in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello everyone
I will be explaining what i need to do and what i have so far.Ok this is what I have to do...
Show code that has a div width of 300px and a background color of yellow. Do not display the div by default. Create a show link (a href). Using onclick event handler, show the div area. and this is what I have...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" > 
<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"xml: lang = "en"lang = "en" > 
<head>
<meta http - equiv = "content-type"content = "text/html; charset=utf-8" / >
<link rel="stylesheet: href="finalpart3.css" type="text/css" />
<html>
<head>
<title>Final part 3</title>
<script language="JavaScript">
function setVisibility(id, visibility) {
document.getElementById(id).style.display = visibility;
 }
</script>

</head>
<body >
<div id="sub3"><a href="finalpart3.css"><input type="button" name="type" value='Show Layer' onclick="setVisibility('sub3', 'inline');";></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my css file..

```
div {
position: absolute;
left: 100px;
top: 200px;
background-color: #FFDD00;
width: 300px;
padding: 10px;
color: black;
display: none;
 }
```

I know my code is wrong somewhere when you click the link it gives the code but no background color or nothing.My brain is fried at this point in time and I know it is something that is small. Can someone might point out where i need an extra code or something so that way the back ground can show up thanks. Or maybe I am ready it wrong and dont need a background color of yellow and 300px in width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you want to display, but other than epascarello mentioned. There other things you may want to consider. If the `<div id="sub3">` is properly link to the css, your link will not be visible. Also I don't know the purpose of this `<a href="finalpart3.css"`.

Here's my modified version of your `div` check it out if can be a help

```
<div id="sub3"><a href="finalpart3.css">link</a></div>
<input type=button name=type value='Show Layer' onclick="setVisibility('sub3', 'inline');">
```

Comment: Cause i am suppose to use a Create a show link (a href).Is why I have a (a href) in mine

Comment: I see, check the updated code. I just remove the button inside the `div` so you can show the it.

Comment: Thank you i figure it out with a little added help thanks..

Answer (score 3):

Do you see your typo here?

```
<link rel="stylesheet: href=...
```

`:` !== `"` for the closing quote.

Comment: Thank you!!! Now i click a quick box that comes up and goes away...

Comment: well why is my box not staying up when you click the show it.

Comment: Nothing like asking a second question...

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342/187073) by removing these typo-related questions - we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?